# iOS Background Image Being Squished by Navbar

Tags: iphone, ios, background, uinavigationbar, uitabbar

I have an app that is using a `UITabBar` and `UINavigationBar`. I am creating a `UIImageView` that contains my background image and then add that `UIImageView` to my `self.view` as a subview. This causes the background to appear "squished" vertically. The background image is not starting until the bottom of the NavBar and then runs down behind the TabBar.

Here's the code I'm using to add the background:

```
UIImageView* backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
    [backgroundView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    [self.view addSubview:backgroundView];
```

Any ideas about how to keep the actual size of the background would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you create this on an iPhone 5 storyboard?

Comment: Does the container view have the property automatically resize subviews? That could be the problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you won't have 480 points of height to use with a `UINavigationBar` present on anything less than an iPhone/iPod 5. You should use `self.view.frame.size.height` to get the actual size. Really, you should just set the frame to the view's bounds.

```
[backgroundView setFrame:self.view.bounds];
```

Secondly, you should set the `contentMode` property of the `UIImageView`.

```
[backgroundView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill]; //Set UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit if you want to show the full image with the potential of a letterbox
```

That should solve your problems.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking. Yes, any view that belongs to a tab bar controller or navigation controller will be resized to fit the remaining screen space, but you know exactly how much space your image view will have left after considering the space consumed by the other UI elements:

Status bar: 320 x 20 (portrait), 480 x 20 (landscape) Navigation bar: 320 x 44 (portrait), 480 x 34 (landscape) Tab bar: 320 x 49 (portrait), 480 x 49 (landscape)

So basically, you have the following available space for your image view:

Portrait: 320 x 367 Landspace: 480 x 217

Design your Default.png with those dimensions in mind. Honestly, the easiest way to match your first screen with your Default.png is to simply take a screenshot of the iOS Simulator.